# how to make the return value more readable in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey, Guys,
I'm new to rails
When I type `drummer = Drummer.find(1)`,
the console gives me whole bunch of character without a line break, It' really hard to read, same thing when I use  `drummer.methods` to check all the available methods

print method doesn't work, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `puts drummer.methods` then it should give you linebreaks.

A simple way to see your objects formatted would be `puts drummer.to_yaml` a shortcut for that in the rails console is `y drummer`

Comment: You could also use `debug  drummer` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debug)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for something like Hirb to make your time in the rails console easier.

https://github.com/cldwalker/hirb

```
>> require 'hirb'
>> Hirb.enable
>> Post.first
>> ...See tabular data
```

Answer (score 0):

To make tables more human readable in rails console I can do something like

```
quotes.select('close').each { |v| puts v.close }
```